# How to reload view on checkbox click in angular 6

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and want to know how to reload view when we click on checkbox.

I am showing list of images on web page. I want to filter out images based on checkbox selection. i.e show the images corresponding to type based on checkbox selection.

My html code is

```
    <hr/>
    List Of Images

    <input type="checkbox" name="class1" value="class1" data-md-icheck (change)="toggleVisibility($event)"> Male<br>


    <hr/>

<div *ngFor="let i of numArr">
  <ngui-in-view>
    <!-- <img *ngIf src="https://picsum.photos/800/300?image={{i}}" height="33%" width="33%"> -->
    <img *ngIf src="http://localhost:8080/test/{{i}}.jpg" height="33%" width="33%">
  </ngui-in-view>
</div>

<div class="num-images">
  Number of &lt;img> tag on document: {{numImages}}
</div>
```

And Component code is

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-img',
  templateUrl: './img.component.html',
  styles: [ `
    ngui-in-view {
      min-height: 300px;

    }
    .num-images { 
      position: fixed; padding: 5px;
      bottom: 0; right: 0; background: #333;color: #fff;
    }` ]
})

export class ImgComponent  {

 classname = ""

 get numImages(): number {
    return this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('img').length;
  }

   numArr = Array.from(Array(3), (_,x) => x)

  toggleVisibility(e){

   console.log(e)

  }



  constructor(public element: ElementRef) {}

}
```

Here on click of checkbox i am planning to load filtered out images. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it really simple, thanks to `ApplicationRef` - https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef

Method named `tick()` can be used for manual refresh of the view.

```
export class Component {
    constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef) {}
}

toggleVisibility(e){
    console.log(e);
    this.appRef.tick();
}
```

Comment: In the toggleVisibility() function I just updated numArr val and it is working for me without calling appRef.tick().  Not sure if avoiding appRef.tick() is proper way ?

Comment: If your view is updated then what is the purpose of the question? :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any logic of the filtering, but let's assume you wanted to filter out all images according to the checkbox.

Declare a variable in your class called `showImages`. Add to the `<img>` in the template `*ngIf="showImages"`, and on `change` event of the `checkbox`, toggle the value of `showImages` -

```
toggleVisibility(e) { 
  this.showImages = !this.showImages;
}
```

On this base, I hope you'll be able to set your logic for the filtering of the images.